# Python - JSON to CSV converter explanation

Tags: python, json, csv

I am doing a data analysis project and I need to convert the files from JSON to CSV. I have discovered this code but as I have not studied Python yet I'm unsure what to do. I'm not sure where I put the file directory or the column names.

If someone would be able to explain where I do this I'd appreciate it!

```
import argparse
import collections
import csv
import simplejson as json


def read_and_write_file(json_file_path, csv_file_path, column_names):
    """Read in the json dataset file and write it out to a csv file,given the column names."""
    with open(csv_file_path, 'wb+') as fout:
    csv_file = csv.writer(fout)
    csv_file.writerow(list(column_names))
    with open(json_file_path) as fin:
        for line in fin:
            line_contents = json.loads(line)
            csv_file.writerow(get_row(line_contents, column_names))

 def get_superset_of_column_names_from_file(json_file_path):
"""Read in the json dataset file and return the superset of column  names."""
column_names = set()
with open(json_file_path) as fin:
    for line in fin:
        line_contents = json.loads(line)
        column_names.update(
                set(get_column_names(line_contents).keys())
                )
return column_names

 def get_column_names(line_contents, parent_key=''):
"""Return a list of flattened key names given a dict.
Example:
    line_contents = {
        'a': {
            'b': 2,
            'c': 3,
            },
    }
    will return: ['a.b', 'a.c']
These will be the column names for the eventual csv file.
"""
column_names = []
for k, v in line_contents.iteritems():
    column_name = "{0}.{1}".format(parent_key, k) if parent_key else k
    if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
        column_names.extend(
                get_column_names(v, column_name).items()
                )
    else:
        column_names.append((column_name, v))
return dict(column_names)

def get_nested_value(d, key):
"""Return a dictionary item given a dictionary `d` and a flattened key from `get_column_names`.

Example:
    d = {
        'a': {
            'b': 2,
            'c': 3,
            },
    }
    key = 'a.b'
    will return: 2

"""
if '.' not in key:
    if key not in d:
        return None
    return d[key]
base_key, sub_key = key.split('.', 1)
if base_key not in d:
    return None
sub_dict = d[base_key]
return get_nested_value(sub_dict, sub_key)

def get_row(line_contents, column_names):
"""Return a csv compatible row given column names and a dict."""
row = []
for column_name in column_names:
    line_value = get_nested_value(
                    line_contents,
                    column_name,
                    )
    if isinstance(line_value, unicode):
        row.append('{0}'.format(line_value.encode('utf-8')))
    elif line_value is not None:
        row.append('{0}'.format(line_value))
    else:
        row.append('')
return row

if __name__ == '__main__':
"""Convert a yelp dataset file from json to csv."""

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Convert Yelp Dataset Challenge data from JSON format to CSV.',
        )

parser.add_argument(
        'json_file',
        type=str,
        help='The json file to convert.',
        )

args = parser.parse_args()

json_file = args.json_file
csv_file = '{0}.csv'.format(json_file.split('.json')[0])

column_names = get_superset_of_column_names_from_file(json_file)
read_and_write_file(json_file, csv_file, column_names)
```

Comment: If you're trying to do this just once I would suggest using a module like pandas to get this done with minimal effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the json file is one of the arguments when you run the script and the column names are mapped from the json file.

So it should work if you run this script like this:

```
python script.py json_file.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't put the file directory anywhere. The path is generated by replacing json with csv in the original filename. As for the column names, these are garnered in get_superset_of_column_names_from_file(). Indeed you need only run this as `python yelp.json` and it will spit out yelp.csv after determining the column names itself.